# How to view Stack Trace of a process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, proc, stack

I have seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166580/389384) answer and according to that Stack Trace can be seen like:

```
$ cat /proc/<PID>/stack
[<ffffffff81012b72>] save_stack_trace_tsk+0x22/0x40
[<ffffffff81213abe>] proc_pid_stack+0x8e/0xe0
[<ffffffff81214960>] proc_single_show+0x50/0x90
[<ffffffff811cd970>] seq_read+0xe0/0x3e0
[<ffffffff811a6a84>] vfs_read+0x94/0x180
[<ffffffff811a7729>] SyS_read+0x49/0xb0
[<ffffffff81623ad2>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

From what I guess, in line

```
[<ffffffff81012b72>] save_stack_trace_tsk+0x22/0x40
```

**save_stack_trace_tsk** definitely refers to name of function
What do the other parameters indicate? (Perhaps **0xffffffff81012b72** points to address of starting address of **save_stack_trace_tsk**+0x22)
Most importantly what does 0x40 denote?
Does 0x40 denote the total number of bytes taken by that particular function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: does 0x40 denote the total number of bytes in that funtion?

Comment: yes, it's offset/size.

Comment: Notice that the address in brackets is always `[<0>]` in newer kernels, see [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8f5abe842e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `save_stack_trace_tsk+0x22/0x40`, `0x22` is the offset inside the the `save_stack_trace_tsk` function, and `0x40` is the size of the `save_stack_trace_tsk` function. Both hex numbers are in bytes.

This is the result of the `%pB` format specifier extension used by the kernel's `printf` implementation: for details, including how the end (thence the size) of the function is determined, you can have a look at the `lib/vsprintf.c` and `kernel/kallsyms.c` in the linux kernel source code.

The `[<0xffffffff81012b72>]` is the same `save_stack_trace_tsk+0x22` kernel address, but in raw form.

That's always `[<0>]` in newer kernels, since [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8f5abe842e) change.